# Nesting variables in JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm trying to set up my Firebase database to have 3 levels, the top level being a patientID, the second being a date (passed as a string), and the last being some questions with the associated answers said patient inputted.

The below code shows roughly how I'd like it laid out, and when running it a screenshot of Firebase's database layout is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxCok.png).

The issue I am facing is that when running the function as shown below, I'd like the topmost level to be named "testID", and the second to be "1-1-19". However, the function is not passing through these inputted variables, and instead just passing the variable names, as can be seen in the screenshot.

Is it possible to set out the database like this? This is so I can add multiple patientIDs easily, as well as multiple dates for each patientID, and then finally the questions answered on each date.

```
function writeUserData(patientID, date, question1a, question1b, question1c, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8a, question8b, question8c) {
  firebase.database().ref("patients/").set({
    patientID: {
      date: {
        "question1a": question1a,
        "question1b": question1b,
        "question1c": question1c,
        "question2": question2,
        "question3": question3,
        "question4": question4,
        "question5": question5,
        "question6": question6,
        "question7": question7,
        "question8a": question8a,
        "question8b": question8b,
        "question8c": question8c
      }
    }
  });
}

writeUserData("testID", "1-1-19", 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Admittedly not familiar with firebase, but given native JS, I'd try putting the property names in square brackets. (E.g. `[date]:` instead of `date:`)

Comment: This worked as expected, thanks, however due to how I defined the function if I then changed the date it would completely override any previously written data. It seems like @Mocas' idea works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be

```
  firebase.database().ref("patients/").child("testID").child("1-1-19").set({
        "question1a": question1a,
        "question1b": question1b,
        "question1c": question1c,
        "question2": question2,
        "question3": question3,
        "question4": question4,
        "question5": question5,
        "question6": question6,
        "question7": question7,
        "question8a": question8a,
        "question8b": question8b,
        "question8c": question8c    
  });
```

Obviously you can pass variable instead to the "testID" and "1-1-19" when you need to

You can also do this

```
  firebase.database().ref("patients/" + "testID" + "/" + "1-1-19").set({....
```

And replace the strings with your variables, whatever suits you